# Developing JNI applications with Eclipse (Combined Java/C++)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, eclipse-cdt

Have anyone successfully managed to setup a combined Java/C++ project for Eclipse?

What I am trying to do is quite simple;

```
1) Compile my Java sources
2) Run Javah to create the JNI interface
3) Compile all the C/C++ sources
4) Link native shared library + package the JAR
```

Hints or even real projects which work are much welcome.

(Eclipse 3.5)

Comment: This isn't really related to your question but I'm curious: do you need to use JNI/C++? If so, what for? Is it something Java NIO could do?

Comment: The JNI is a bridge between Java and some old crypto hardware, and the API for the device is only available as a c-library.
Right now I have two eclipse projects, one for java classes and second for the native parts in C.
Unnecessary, I think Eclipse should be able to do it in one. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really sounds like a job for a build system, like `ant`.  Simply configure your Java project to use the [ant builder](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t65486.html).  You would still get the benefits of language specific support for your C++ and Java projects, and, one click build of the project.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~eclipse/8-JNI.pdf
I think this is what you wanted.Maybe a little old.

Comment: I don't see any Eclipse references in that document. For a general JNI overview, nothing beats [The Java Native Interface - Programmer's Guide and Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) from Oracle.

As for @ointment's original problem (which I am currently experiencing), I think I'll just have to use a good old-fashioned command line interface (possibly via an Ant task) to build my C++/Java JNI projects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [ant cpptasks](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/cpptasks/index.html) for realizing a JNI project with Eclipse only on Linux and Windows. It was some work to get it running with the MSVC (Windows) and the GNU C++ compiler (getting all compiler and linker flags properly since has been done with Visual Studio Magic before) but it was really worth it.

For generating the C++ Header with javah and all the other Tasks you mentioned [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) will probably be the tool of choice, too.