# JNI for java using eclipse in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-native-interface

Can anybody help me find a tutorial on creating JNI applications using eclipse on the ubuntu platform?

I am finding tutorials for the windows platform, but not for Ubuntu or Linux system.

Comment: I don't think that the Java side of things is any different, but rather it's the C/C++ side which will be platform specific. What type of tutorial are you looking for? How to compile and link C/C++ code with Eclipse?

Comment: I am able to create header file but not .so file. how to do this in ubuntu platform using eclipse. to create library file in windows is dll format. but what is in ubuntu??

Comment: This may be compiler dependent. Which C/C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: Yep, the GNU Compiler Collection comes with Ubuntu I think. Have you looked [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/programming-languages/c-and-c-plus-plus/) yet? There are also Eclipse-specific tut's available through Google.

Comment: Also, Google gave me [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecc/). It's a bit old, but still has relevant information.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I searched but i did't get tut's in google specific to ubuntu :(

Comment: Again, tutorials for what specifically?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: in eclipse property->c/c++ build->settings--> GCC Linker---> miscellaneous--->Linker flags I added -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias. but this is not working. I think this is foe window. I have to give this for ubuntu. this is am not getting

Comment: @Prasad: what's not working? show some error messages eclipse gives you. there are no mind readers here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I am using "http://www.lithiumhead.com/notes/windows_jni" this link for JNI I created .h file successfuly but problem is like Multiple markers at this line
 - fatal error: ..\01Java_HelloWorld\com_lithiumhead_jni_HelloWorld.h: No such file or 
  directory  in a c file

Comment: @Prasad: replace \ with / on unix. I assume you made sure the file is accessible at that path.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624344/developing-jni-applications-with-eclipse-combined-java-c?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

look to [JNA](http://today.java.net/article/2009/12/20/simplify-native-code-access-jna). It is easier. No boilerplate or generated glue code is required.

Comment: There are several valid reasons for using JNI over JNA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556421/use-jni-instead-of-jna-to-call-native-code